# NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have added the Devise gem to the ruby on rails app version 1.8.7. I using devise to authenticate and also I have created a model called user which will connect another database, I have mentioned/specified the database configurations in the create_connection,whenever I run the app in the local host, I am getting this error message

"undefined method `password_salt=' for #"
As soon as I register a new member I am getting this error.

I am a newbie to rails,

Kindly help me out

Comment: ruby v 1.8.7 i assume is what you are saying above, rails version 3 something?

Comment: @Alex Marchant : yup ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had this error once before, try the following

**1.Re-run your migrations again**

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0  #to rollback migrations to the first one if needed<br />
```

Just in case you have forgotten, uncomment the following line

```
t.string :password_salt
```

then migrate your database

```
rake db:migrate
```

Also make sure that encryptable is added to your database model

```
devise :encryptable .....
```

**2.Update your devise gem**

bundle update or specify in your gem file to use latest devise gem 2.x

Comment: @JeevanDongre Glad to help, was your gem out of date?

Comment: Nope i was not aware of the rollback thing, though I removed the comment of the password_salt.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `password_salt` column to your users table. It appears to be missing.

Comment: I added the password_salt column to users table, but still I am getting the same error